# Why am I getting a 'closed' exception when trying to write OkHttp response to .json file in Kotlin?

Tags: api, kotlin, file-io, okhttp

I am trying to make a Currency Conversion App in Kotlin and have a problem with updating my values. The connection works fine but I cannnot write it into an .json file.
Here is my Code:

```
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).header("apikey", key).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                println(response.body()?.string())
                val date = LocalDate.now()
                val osw = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("$date.json", MODE_PRIVATE))
                osw.write(response.body()?.string())
                println("finished")
            }
        })
    }
```

```
Here is the Error: 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.appdevelopment_assignment_7, PID: 6787
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:398)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:392)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:431)
        at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
        at com.example.appdevelopment_assignment_7.ComplexCurrencyConversionActivity$update$1.onResponse(ComplexCurrencyConversionActivity.kt:36)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

The problematic line is `osw.write(response.body()?.string())`. I hope someone might have an idea what could be the problem because I'm stuck here quite a while and couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance and Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can call `string()` on `ResponseBody` only once, as `okhttp` reads the data from stream and does not hold reference, it throws closed as it has already closed the stream post reading! You need to call `string()` and store value inside a variable and then use it multiple times.

```
val request = Request.Builder().url(url).header("apikey", key).build()

val client = OkHttpClient()
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        val responseBody = response.body()?.string() // stream closed after invoking string()
        println(responseBody)
        val date = LocalDate.now()
        val osw = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("$date.json", MODE_PRIVATE))
        osw.write(responseBody)
        println("finished")
    }
})
}
```